# .NET C++ memory leaks using old syntax?

Tags: c++, .net, syntax, memory-leaks, managed-c++

I am working on a memory leak issue in my app. I narrowed it to the old syntax to declare the 'Single' type. Created a test app with the declaration and it is crashing after eating up lots of memory. What am I missing?

Test code is here:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace System;

int main()
{
    while(1)
    {
        System::Single * sngTemp =  new System::Single(0.0);
        //System::String  ^sngTemp =  gcnew System::String(S"dsfasdfasdf");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's your question? Surely you aren't asking why that code crashes. You're allocating memory and not freeing it.

Comment: is the question "why do I only get garbage collection when I use gcnew, and not when I use new?"

Comment: delnan, I was intentionally not freeing. I am expecting GC to do!! Am I wrong?

Comment: Kate, Your question is close to what I am looking an aswer for.

Comment: @MaheswaranRamados the name "gcnew" is a clue. This is C++ and we decide what we want and don't want. You want garbage collection? Use gcnew. You want to do it yourself? Don't use gcnew.

Answer (score 5):

This is not an "old syntax" vs. "new syntax" issue -- C++/CLI would have the same behavior. `System::Single` is an alias for `float`, which can be allocated on the stack, unmanaged heap, or managed heap.

Here, because you're using undecorated `new`, you're allocating one on the unmanaged heap, i.e. doing the exact same as:

```
float* sngTemp = new float(0.0);
```

Why *wouldn't* one expect this to leak? If you want garbage collection, use a managed allocation
(`__gc new` in old syntax); or better yet, don't allocate value types on the heap at all, making it a non-issue.

Comment: Thank you. I think that clears it. I was expecting the System::Single works same as others such as System::String. The difference I see is that Single is documented as a Structure and String as Class , may be this is the clue that one needs if it is GCed or not. Thank you again.